# ReadDirectoryChangesW Asynchronous Completion routine called after I close the handle

Tags: winapi, readdirectorychangesw

I am using `ReadDirectoryChangesW` to monitor when a file has changed within a directory. I am using the asynchronous version of it with a completion routine function, (as per the docs).

Everything works fine until I wish to stop monitoring the folder.

To stop the monitoring I call the `Close` function.

The problem is that I still get one last notification, but by then I have destroyed my `LPOVERLAPPED` value.

How can I stop `ReadDirectoryChangesW` and prevent my `MyCompletionRoutine` function from being called.

```
// get the handle    
_handle = CreateFileW( ... )

void Read()
{
  ...
  ReadDirectoryChangesW( _handle, ..., &MyCompletionRoutine );
  ...
}

void Close()
{
  ::CancelIo(_handle );           
  ::CloseHandle(_handle );
}

void __stdcall MyCompletionRoutine (
    const unsigned long dwErrorCode,
    const unsigned long dwNumberOfBytesTransfered,
    _OVERLAPPED* lpOverlapped )
{
  // ... do stuff and start a read again
  Read();
}
```

In the code above I might have called `Read` but I want to stop before `MyCompletionRoutine` is called.

Not sure if that helps, but the error message I get is `317`

Comment: You jerked the floor mat, it must complete.  You can't safely delete the OVERLAPPED until then, the possible memory corruption is quite hard to diagnose.

Comment: Sorry, not sure I understand what you mean, what boolean variable? The completion routine is a static function, and the `LPOVERLAPPED` is no longer useful, (it is undefined by then).

Comment: you can delete memory to which pointed *lpOverlapped* only after I/O complete - this mean if `ReadDirectoryChangesW` return false or inside callback

Comment: Yes, I understand, but the problem is that after I close the handle, (between a read and a callback), I do not want any more messages. What if I never got a callback for example? I cannot just keep lpOverlapped for ever in the hope it will be called.

Comment: @FFMG if i/o started ok (`ReadDirectoryChangesW `) return true - you have guarantee that it will be finished. it finished after call `CloseHandle` on file or `CancelIo` . when i/o finished - apc will be queued to your thread (because you use apc completion). but user mode apc will be called only when you do alertable wait or call `NtTestAlert`. and problem is that you not understand internal object management here. what and when free/delete.

Comment: @RbMm, please have a look at my accepted answer. It might help you understand what is actually happening.
Feel free to ask if you have any further questions.

Comment: @FFMG - i very good know what is happening internal here :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are closing your `HANDLE` and freeing your `OVERLAPPED` too soon.

`CancelIo()` (and its cross-thread brother, `CancelIoEx()`) simply mark active I/O operations as cancelled and then exit, but you still need to actually wait for those operations to fully complete before you can then free their `OVERLAPPED`.

If an operation notices the cancellation before completing its work, it will stop its work and report a completion with an error code of `ERROR_OPERATION_ABORTED`, otherwise it will finish its work normally and report a completion with the appropriate error code.

After calling `CancelIo/Ex()`, you need to continue waiting on and handling completed operations, until there are no more operations left to wait on.

In other words, `MyCompletionRoutine()` can indeed be called after `CancelIo()` is called, and it needs to check for `ERROR_OPERATION_ABORTED` before calling `Read()` again.  And if there is a pending read in progress when `CancelIo()` is called, you need to wait for that read to complete.

Comment: Thanks, I added `SleepEx(...)` as well as a flag _after_ calling `CancelIo` and I was finally getting `ERROR_OPERATION_ABORTED`

Comment: *`CancelIo` are asynchronous* - strictly saying this is false. `CancelIo` [wait](https://github.com/Aekras1a/Labs/blob/master/Labs/WRK/base/ntos/io/iomgr/misc.c#L213) until all active I/O request will be completed (this true and in modern versions) but another question - when user mode get notification about this. in case APC completion - apc(`MyCompletionRoutine`) can be called only inside several api calls (alertable wait or `NtTestAlert`) so it always will be called after `CancelIo` (or `CloseHandle` call) but only if app do alertable wait after this (or call `NtTestAlert`)